# spring boot validation using jstl(JSP Page) not working

Tags: maven, validation, spring-boot, jstl, hibernate-validator

I am facing the problem in displaying Validation error messages in JSP page. Please see the picture.
[Snapshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDBJd.png)

I am Getting the Validation message in the form of hashcode. actual message is com.vikash.validator.UserValidator@6fec3d47

---

pom.xml

---

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.vikash</groupId>
<artifactId>DevelopementEnv2</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>DevelopementEnv2</name>
<description>Login using Spring MVC</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

here is the main controller . I am trying to use validation while posting into database for only one field ie. username field.

MainController

---

```
package com.vikash.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.vikash.model.User;
import com.vikash.services.UserService;
import com.vikash.validator.UserValidator;

@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_HOME");
        return "allusers";

    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_LOGIN");
        return "allusers";
    }



@RequestMapping("/login-user")
    public String loginUser(@ModelAttribute User user, HttpServletRequest request) {

        if (userService.findByUsernameAndPassword(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword()) != null) {
            return "welcome";
        } else {
            request.setAttribute("error", "Invalid Username or Password");
            request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_LOGIN");
            return "allusers";
        }

    }

    @RequestMapping("/registration")
    public String registration(HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.setAttribute("mode", "USER_REGISTRATION");
        return "allusers";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save-user")
    public String registe(@ModelAttribute @Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) {

        UserValidator obj = new UserValidator();
        obj.validate(user, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            request.setAttribute("error", obj);
        request.setAttribute("mode", "USER_REGISTRATION");
            return "allusers";
        }
        userService.saveUser(user);
        request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_HOME");
        return "allusers";
    }

    @GetMapping("/show-users")
    public String showUsers(HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.setAttribute("users", userService.showAllUsers());
        request.setAttribute("mode", "ALL_USERS");
        return "allusers";
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete-user")
    public String deleteUser(@RequestParam int id, HttpServletRequest request) {
        userService.deleteSelectedUser(id);
        request.setAttribute("users", userService.showAllUsers());
        request.setAttribute("mode", "ALL_USERS");
        return "allusers";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/edit-user")
    public String editUser(@RequestParam int id, HttpServletRequest request) {
        request.setAttribute("user", userService.editUser(id));
        request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_EDIT");
        return "allusers";
    }

}
```

User.java class

```
package com.vikash.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name="mytable")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    private int  id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String  username;   

    private String firstname;   

    private String lastname;    

    private int age;

    private String password;


    public User() {

    }   

    public User(String username, String firstname, String lastname, int age, String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.age = age;
        this.password = password;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", username=" + username + ", firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname
                + ", age=" + age + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }

}
```

UserValidation.java

```
package com.vikash.validator;

import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import com.vikash.model.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;

@Validated
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

        return User.class.equals(clazz) ;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

        User user = (User) target;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "Username can not be blank");
    }
}
```

JSP page.

```
<c:when test="${mode=='USER_REGISTRATION'}">
        <div class="container text-center">



        <hr>
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="save-user">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${user.id }" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Username</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"
                        value="${user.username }" />
                </div>
                <c:out value="${error }"></c:out>


            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname"
                        value="${user.firstname }" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname"
                        value="${user.lastname }" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Age </label>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age"
                        value="${user.age }" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Password</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                        value="${user.password }" />

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group ">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</c:when>
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've posted a lot of code here. Have you tried reproducing the problem in isolation? What have you already tried? Have a look at the Help Center to see how to write a great question (stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The full block of code is present in git repository link: https://github.com/vikash-kohimam99/MyApplication--SpringBoot-Login-and-Registration-youtube.git it would be helpful if someone can apply validation to user registration form.